# What is the meaning of the using 0x1 in #define?

Tags: c

I came across a line of code which had something like the below

```
#define IM 0x1
```

I do know what IM stands for, but I am intrested in knowing what `0x1` stands for and what is its use and its significance for usage in define statements.

I am new to C and I did search for this particular item but could not find it. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Probably the author used 0x1 to comply with the other variables implicit standard, like Sasquiha exemplified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the hexadecimal number 1, usually define like this when doing binary flags. So you would have

```
0x1
0x2
0x4
0x8
0x10
```

so you can see the bits you are setting.

Comment: I'd go for 1<<n, it's much clearer and constant, the compiler will optimize anyway.

Comment: @Spidey I don't believe plain hex, with the purpose of bit masking as in this case, is unclear. If the person who reads the code doesn't understand hex, they better step away from the computer and hand the code over to a programmer instead.

Answer (score 9):

It is just a define for the number one in hexadecimal (base 16). This is probably used to avoid magic numbers in the code. Magic numbers are when a programmer use direct numbers in code without explanation. For instance

```
int x = 32;
x -= 8;
```

This code along makes hardly any sense, but if I do this

```
#define TOTAL_BITS 32
#define BITS_PER_BYTE 8

int x = TOTAL_BITS;
x -= BITS_PER_BYTE;
```

The code is significantly more clear. In any event, macros (i.e. `#define`) directly replace their contents to where they show up in code. So if you are going to use an expression or similar, it is best to surround it with parens.

Answer (score 4):

It's the number one expressed in hexadecimal (base 16) form.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Answer (score 3):

```
#define IM    0x1
```

It's an other positional numeral system : the hexadecimal. Here, it's the hexadecimal form of the number « 1 ».